# Django identify bottle necks in application code?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django and I need software to help me identify bottle necks in my application code. My CPU  is 90% all the time! I have looked at newrelic but for solo guy it's too expensive at $140 per month for what I need.

My question is, are they any server performance monitoring tools for Django/python on the market other than newrelic that does the same job? or are they any packages that would be useful? I have search the web and it turned up very little. I'm open to idea of how others identify problem code in Django without such a tool!

Comment: How many users do you have at any one time? Maybe it's time to scale horizontally.

Comment: yeah, but I would like to know where the issue is first, could even be an easy fix who knows?

Comment: First recommendation would be to install Django debug toolbar, and look at profiling information, such as query response times, and other obvious bottlenecks, etc..

Comment: The profiler tells you where bottleneck is. Run some of those cpu-burning requests and then check profiler's output.

Comment: @ yedpodtrzitko I have the Django debug toolbar locally installed, but that does not simulate the level of requests happening in the live environment. It's very hard to guess what is happening. I need something in Django which can watch and report back from live server like newrelic, but without the arm and leg cost.

Comment: What server software are you using? Apache?

Comment: just a comment, what about dogslow? https://dogslow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#usage

Comment: @mitchfish36 yes it's Apache

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://munin-monitoring.org/ and http://www.nagios.org/ - both have great reviews from my peers (at least 10 people I work with have sworn by them, as I reached the same fork as you about a month ago, and asked around). Though I've not used either myself, I intend to set up both later this week.